# invalid path for setGlobal error in console how to debug

Tags: javascript

I have this error in console and I think that it blocks some other JS from executing..  Does anyone have an idea what it is or how to debug?I did not declare this variable anywhere and can not find it with cmd shift f .. Would appreciate any help [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeZjL.png)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where my JS was not executing, turned out that my browser prevented 3rd party script cookies from executing.

By unchecking the setting 'Block 3rd party cookies and site data', or 'Allow 3rd party cookies' in Brave, the site executed.

If your users have this blocked as well, they will have problems running your site as well.

[image]
courtesy to [Chromium.org](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines/uncaught-securityerror-failed-to-read-the-localstorage-property-from-window-access-is-denied-for-this-document)